# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors - putting in the form $PDP^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Okay so I just need some help towards the end, if possible. I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix that looks like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 10 \\
-30 & -17
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to find all eigenvectors and eigenvalues corresponding to it - I've done that, I think. I got two eigenvalues which are $3$ and $-2$. Then I tried to express this matrix in the form $PDP^{-1}$. I came up with:

$$
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\   
-3 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm not sure if D should be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or if the $-2$ and $3$ should be switched about. I've tried both anyway.

$$
P^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-3 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I try to multiply them together to check that I get the same as my original matrix, but I seem to get the wrong values (but tantalisingly close). 
For example, with the three above I get $(18 \hspace{.15cm} 10)$ for $a$ and $b$, which is good but for $c$ and $d$ I get, ($-18+12=-6  -9+8$=-1) respectively, though I need -30 and -17 in those positions..

I must have made a mistake along the way but am not sure which it is - any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of your matrix are indeed $3$ and $-2$.
You must have also computed the eigenvectors associated with each eigenvalues and found them to be:

$$v_{3} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}^T \quad ; \quad v_{-2} =\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^T.$$

(the subscript represents the eigenvalue to which the eigenvector is associated with)

The way you write your matrix $P$ is directly related to the way you want to write your matrix $D$.

If you want to write $D = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0\\ 
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$
then the first column of $P$ will be $v_3$ and the second one will be $v_{-2}$, i.e., $P = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\ 
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$, in which case
$P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1\\ 
3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.$

If you want to write $D = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0\\ 
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$
then the first column of $P$ will be $v_{-2}$ and the second one will be $v_3$, i.e. $P = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2\\ 
2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$, in which case
$P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2\\ 
-2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: I have my eigenvectors as 3[2  -3] and -2[1  -2], but yours appear to be the other way around?

Comment: @MathsNoob2015, any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector for the given eigenvalue. In fact, let's consider a matrix $A$ and take $v$ as an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e., $Av = \lambda v$. Now, consider a scalar multiple of $v$, say $\alpha v$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, we have $A(\alpha v) = \alpha (Av) = \alpha (\lambda v) = \lambda (\alpha v).$

I just happens that both my eigenvectors are $-1$ times your eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

You must have made a mistake when multiplying the matrices at the end, for your matrices $P,P^{-1},D$ are all correct.

Got it - should be $-18-12$, not $-18+12$. Similarly, the other entry should be $-9-8$. This way you get $-30$ and $-17$.

Comment: Correct. It's not until I typed them up on here that it was made more clear. Thanks for affirming.

Answer (score 0):

you have $\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 10 \\
-30 & -17
\end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{2\\-3} = 3\pmatrix{2\\-3}\tag 1$
  and $\begin{bmatrix}
18 & 10 \\
-30 & -17
\end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{1\\-2} = 3=-2\pmatrix{1\\-2}\tag 2$

writing $(1)$ and $(2)$ as matrix equation you get 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
18 & 10 \\
-30 & -17
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-3 & -2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-3 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

Comment: You should actually have $AP=PD$, not $AP=DP$. (A diagonal matrix multiplying on the left rescales rows rather than columns.)

Comment: @ian, you are right. it is fixed now.